# TypeError: Cannot destructure property `body` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: javascript

I have the following error in the console:

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property `body` of 'undefined' or
>   'null'.

This is my code:

```
var { body } = await snekfetch.get(`https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=${userArray[i]}`).catch((err) => console.log('caught it'));
        if (body.success === false){
          var errorEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor(0xff4040)
            .setDescription(`:warning: **${userArray[i]} doesn't exist on ROBLOX** :warning:`);
            await message.channel.send(errorEmbed);
```

Comment: add try and catch and check if you have any error in console.

Comment: Can I catch them like this? .catch((err) => console.log('caught it'));

Comment: Use, try { <your code> } catch(error) {}.

Comment: So only `var { body } = await snekfetch.get(`https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=${userArray[i]}`).catch((err) => console.log('caught it'));`
or the whole code?

Comment: Added the answer

Comment: Try to `console.log()` your data first. The error says that you don't get anything from the URL, thence `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: It's still showing the same error even though I checked and the URL is still working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
try {
  var response = await snekfetch.get(
    `https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=${userArray[i]}`
  );
  if (response && response.body && response.body.success) {
    var errorEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor(0xff4040)
      .setDescription(
        `:warning: **${userArray[i]} doesn't exist on ROBLOX** :warning:`
      );
    await message.channel.send(errorEmbed);
  } else {
    console.log('Error');
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: A new error appeared: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'

Comment: I have. It shows another error: Unexpected token 'else'

Comment: There are many get calls, you have to change all the calls as above.

Comment: Would you mind doing it for me some of it like examples, because I don't have much knowledge about Javascript? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the delay . I have already provided you the example in answer.